# How to return promise.map (bluebird) inside a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm using a chain to control flow and can't get promise.map in `step2()` to wait until all of it's generated promises are resolved.

Here's a visual of the flow I'm trying to achieve.

`step1()
       step2()
       step2()
       step2()
       step2()
              step3()`

In `step2()` I'm using Bluebird's promise.map.

Here's the chain:

```js
step1()
  .then(function() { return step2() }) 
  .then(function() { return step3() })
  .catch(function() { // handle errors })
```

Here's my functions for each step:

```js
let step1 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
    // do stuff
    resolve()
  })
}

let step2 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    things = []      
    return Promise.map(things, function(thing) {
      // load file async with callback
    })
    resolve()
  })
}

let step3 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
    // do stuff
    resolve()
  })
}
```

I've tested the chain with many more steps each with a `timeout` and it worked as expected with the exception of the promise.map in `step2()`. What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: in `step2` the call to `resolve()` is unreachable. `return` effectively stops execution of your code, so any code after it will not be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is from step 2. `Promise.map` already return promise, so you can just return it to callee. Then you warp the async function with callback with `new Promise`.

```
let step2 = function() {
  things = []      
  return Promise.map(things, function(thing) {
    // load file async with callback
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fileAsyncFunc(thing, function callback(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: And it works! But just out of curiosity if you use a timeout to fake an async call it doesn't work ... why would that be?

Comment: i don't really understand your question, how do you fake an async call with timeout? it's probably just because async call finished before the timeout so that you got the result from the async call, but it's not an good idea because you will never know which one finish first.

Comment: Yeah, never mind, I thought by just using a timeout it would approximate doing an actual async call. My lazy way of testing. Anyway, with an actual async call to load a file it works wonderfully, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your `resolve` callback properly.

```
let step2 = function() {
    things = []      
    return Promise.map(things, function(thing) {         
      return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
          // load file async with callback
          resolve(...)
      } )
    })
}
```

In your case `resolve()` is always called, since you are executing async function for loading the file.